# How to render Python user input in Quarto?

Tags: python, input, rstudio, quarto

I'm using RStudio to render a Quarto document that demonstrates the functionality of python's `input()` function. I've had trouble rendering python in the past using the jupyter engine in RStudio, so I have been using the [`reticulate`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) package and rendering with the `knitr` engine. This works when python chunks in the document do not have any input values. But a .qmd document with the following content ...

```py
def get_input():
    x = input("give me an input: ")
    print("Your input is ", "\"" + str(x) + "\"")

get_input()
Hello world. # <-- user input

get_input()
23 # <-- user input
```

... will yield the message below and fail to render. When I run this chunk in RStudio it prints the correct output with no errors.

```
Quitting from lines 8-17 (test.qmd) 
Error: invalid syntax (<string>, line 6)

Execution halted
```

The invalid syntax error is in reference to line 6 of the code chunk occupying line 8-17 of test.qmd, which is the "Hello world." user input line. Lines 1-7 are the YAML header which is included below.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there some other way to place user input values in a code chunk that won't cause rendering issues?
2. Is this an issue that can be fixed using a different engine (i.e. not knitr) to render?

Here it the YAML header I'm using:

```yaml
---
title: "test"
author: "mattrex"
format: html
engine: knitr
---
```